# Checking Linearity of $T:\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})\to\mathbf{R^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

Is the Following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** Given that $b,c\in\mathbf{R}$. Define $T:\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{R})\to \mathbf{R^2}$
$$Tp=(3p(4),5p'(6)+bp(1)p(2),\int_{-1}^{2}x^3p(x)dx+c\sin p(0))$$
Show that $T$ is linear if and only if $b=c=0$.

**Proof.** $(\Rightarrow).$ Assume that $T$ as defined above is Linear and let $p_1,p_2\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ such that 
$$p_1(1),p_2(1),p_1(2),p_2(2)\neq 0\tag{1}$$ and 
$$\forall q\in\mathbf{Z}(p_1(0),p_2(0)\neq \ q\pi)\tag{2}$$
The linearity of $T$ implies that $T(p_1+p_2)=T(p_1)+T(p_2)$. Thus 
$$T(p_1+p_2)=(3(p_1(4)+p_2(4)),5(p_1'(6)+p_2'(6))+$$
$$b(p_1(1)+p_2(1))(p_1(2)+p_2(2)),\int_{-1}^{2}x^3(p_1(x)+p_2(x))dx+c\sin (p_1(0)+p_2(0)))\tag{3}$$
and 
$$T(p_1)+T(p_2)=(3(p_1(4)+p_2(4)),5(p_1'(6)+p_2'(6))+$$
$$b(p_1(1)p_1(2)+p_2(1)p_2(2)),\int_{-1}^{2}x^3(p_1(x)+p_2(x))dx+c(\sin p_1(0)+\sin p_2(0))\tag{4}$$
From the above two equations we may deduce that 
$$b(p_1(1)+p_2(1))(p_1(2)+p_2(2))=b(p_1(1)p_1(2)+p_2(1)p_2(2))\tag{5}$$
$$c\sin (p_1(0)+p_2(0)))=c(\sin p_1(0)+\sin p_2(0))\tag{6}$$

After some Algebraic manipulation we have 
$$0=b(p_1(1)p_2(2)+p_2(1)p_1(2))\tag{7}$$
$$0=c(\sin p_1(0)(\cos p_2(0)-1)+\sin p_2(0)(\cos p_1(0)-1))\tag{8}$$
Owing to condition $(1)$ we know that the term in the parenthesis of $(7)$ is $\neq 0$ consequently $b=0$ a similar conclusion can be made about $(8)$ owing to condition $(2)$ implying that $c=0$.

$(\Leftarrow).$ Assume now that $b=c=0$ and let $p_1$ and $p_2$ be arbitrary polynomials in $\mathcal{P(\mathbf{F})}$. Computing $T(p_1+p_2)$ and $T(p_1)+T(p_2)$ for $p_1$ and $p_2$ will yield the same equations as in $(3)$ and $(4)$ but since $b=c=0$ it follows that $T(p_1+p_2)=T(p_1)+T(p_2)$.

Now assume that $p\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbf{F})$ and let $\lambda\in\mathbf{F}$ then 
$$T(\lambda p)=(3\lambda p(4),5\lambda p'(6)+b\lambda p(1)\lambda p(2),\int_{-1}^{2}x^3\lambda p(x)dx+c\sin \lambda p(0))\tag{10}$$
and 
$$\lambda T(p)=(3\lambda p(4),5\lambda p'(6)+\lambda bp(1)p(2),\int_{-1}^{2}x^3\lambda p(x)dx+c\lambda \sin p(0))\tag{11}$$
Since $b=c=0$ it follows that $$T(\lambda p)=\lambda T(p)$$

$\blacksquare$

Comment: How is $T(p) = (3p(4),5p'(6)+bp(1)p(2),\int_{-1}^2 x^3p(x)dx + c\sin p(0))$ from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^2$?  Do you mean $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in general the proof is correct, but you need to be a bit more specific regarding your choice of $p_1$, $p_2$ in the first part of the proof. Simply requiring that $p_1(1),p_1(2),p_2(1),p_2(2) \neq 0$ is not sufficient, because they could have opposite signs and the terms would cancel. You can however require $$p_1(1)=p_1(2)=p_2(1)=p_2(2)=1\,,$$ which would be sufficient. Similarly, for the $\sin p(0)$ term, consider polynomials with 
$$p_1(0) = p_2(0) = \frac \pi 2\,.$$
Otherwise your reasoning is correct.